# Michael Hartl guide chapter 6 syntax error user_spec.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting the following error message:

```
rails_projects/sample_app/spec/models/user_spec.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
@attr = ( :name => "Example User", :email => "user@example.com")
```

After  I setup and only setup the user_spec.rb file
    require 'spec_helper'

```
describe User do

before(:each) do
@attr = ( :name => "Example User", :email => "user@example.com")
#  pending "add seme examples to (or delete) #{__FILE__}"
end

it "should create a new instance given valid attributes" do
User.create!(@attr)
end

it "should require a name"
end
```

I know I will still get a pending message at the code however not a syntax error

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the `{...}` for Hash syntax here:

```
@attr = { :name => "Example User", :email => "user@example.com" }
```

Ps. Just checked the tutorial and [it shows the same](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-and-viewing-users-one#code%3araw_user_spec) - you made a typo, no worries
(The font used for code in the tutorial could have been better!)